# Pentaho add Last Modification Field in Output Table

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

In Pentaho input step, there are the tab Additional Output Field.
I want to use Last Modification Field in output.

What should I write in Last Modification Field so in output it will write timestamp. (Please give example also)

[image: pentaho-access-input]

Thank you.

Comment: You write any name there for the field that will contain the input file last modified date, for example "Last_modified_date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Cyrus suggest, to add **Last modification field** (or any addition field) to the result, just add the field name.

For example, if you write "last_updated" on **Last modification field**, then in result table, you will see the column name "last_updated" contain the time which record is last modified.

Conclusion => add a name to active that field (will appear in result table), no name = deactive (not appear in result table)